# Can someone add the tag "ontology"?

Tags: support, feature-request

I'm wanting to ask some questions dealing with ontological data models.  Can someone add the tag "ontology" to this site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Post a question, flag it for the tag, we'll add it then. That's how tags work.